# Cannot login with bearer token postman

Tags: postman, codeigniter-4

when I login by entering my email and password and get a token. then the token is used to log back in and will display the data in the form of an email and password. but there is an error as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqnJC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jsOz.png)

Source Code
**getbearertoken.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\ModelUsers;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class Me extends ResourceController
{
    /**
     * Return an array of resource objects, themselves in array format
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    use ResponseTrait;
    public function index()
    {
        $key = getenv('TOKEN_SECRET');
        $header = $this->request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
        if(!$header) return $this->failUnauthorized('Token tidak ditemukan');
        $token = explode(' ', $header)[1];

        try {
            $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, ['HS256']);
            $response = [
                'user_id' => $decoded->uid,
                'email' => $decoded->email,
            ];
            return $this->respond($response);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $this->fail('Token tidak valid');
        }
    }

    
}
```

loginbearertoken.php

```
   public function index()
    {
        $key = getenv('TOKEN_SECRET');
        $header = $this->request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');
        if(!$header) return $this->failUnauthorized('Token tidak ditemukan');
        $token = explode(' ', $header)[1];

        try {
            $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, ['HS256']);
            $response = [
                'user_id' => $decoded->uid,
                'email' => $decoded->email,
            ];
            return $this->respond($response);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $this->fail('Token tidak valid');
        }
    }
```

can friends help? I hope answers from friends

Answer (score 0):

You are using jwt token.  Usually jwt token have expiry of hour or day.

if jwt token is expired, most systems use refresh_token to get next token.

```php
try {
            $decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, ['HS256']);
            $response = [
                'user_id' => $decoded->uid,
                'email' => $decoded->email,
            ];
            return $this->respond($response);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $this->fail('Token tidak valid');
        }
```